# Displaying List entries as Checkboxes - Neither BindingResult nor plain available

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following object.

```
public class Anonymization {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "anonymization")
    private List<Host> hosts;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "anonymization")
    private List<Item> items;
```

The objects `Host` and `Item` have several boolean Fields. I want to display a form, where all Host and Item objects are displayed as checkboxes, so that the boolean fields can be edited. I wrote a controller to display the form

```
@RequestMapping("monitoringsystem/{mId}/anonymization")
    public String editAnonymisatzion(Model model, @PathVariable Long mId){
        model.addAttribute("mId", mId);
        model.addAttribute("anonymization", monitoringSystemRepository.findOne(mId).getAnonymization());
        return "monitoringsystem/anonymizationForm";
    }
```

The `anonymizationForm` should display the checkboxes in a for-each-loop

```
<!-- more code --->
<form class="form-horizontal" th:modelAttribute="anonymization" th:object="${anonymization}" th:action="@{'monitoringsystem/' + ${mId} + '/anonymisatzion/save'}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Set Anonymization</legend>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Anonymizie Hostnames</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group" th:each="host : ${anonymization.hosts}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes" th:text="${host.name}"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label for="checkboxes-0">
                                        <input th:field="${host.anonymizeName}" type="checkbox" /> 
                                        anonymizie
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Anonymizie Items</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group" th:each="item : ${anonymization.items}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes" th:text="${item.name}"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label for="checkboxes-0">
                                        <input th:field="${item.anonymizeName}" type="checkbox" /> 
                                        anonymizie name
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label for="checkboxes-0">
                                        <input th:field="${item.anonymizeData}" type="checkbox" /> 
                                        anonymizie data
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<!-- more code --->
```

Unfortunatly when i call the View I'm getting the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'host' available as request attribute
```

I checkt my Database all Relationsships are set correctly. The `List<Host>` should contain 1 and the `List<Item>` 2 entries.

I can't find my mistake.

**UPDATE 1:**

I debuged the anonymization object which is passed to the form. It's is complete. Which means all listentries are present. So I guess the error has something to to do with my view - how I call the object.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myselfe. Fist of all i changes the way the list-objects are called in my form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" th:modelAttribute="anonymization" th:object="${anonymization}" th:action="@{'monitoringsystem/' + ${mId} + '/anonymisatzion/save'}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Set Anonymization</legend>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Anonymizie Hostnames</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group" th:each="host, statHost : *{hosts}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes" th:text="*{hosts[__${statHost.index}__].name}"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label for="checkboxes-0">
                                    <input th:field="*{hosts[__${statHost.index}__].anonymizeName}" type="checkbox" /> 
                                    anonymizie
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Anonymizie Items</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group" th:each="item, statItem : *{items}">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes" th:text="*{items[__${statItem.index}__].name}"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label for="checkboxes-0">
                                    <input th:field="*{items[__${statItem.index}__].anonymizeName}" type="checkbox" /> 
                                    anonymizie name
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label for="checkboxes-0">
                                    <input th:field="*{items[__${statItem.index}__].anonymizeData}" type="checkbox" /> 
                                    anonymizie data
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <a th:href="@{/monitoringsystem}" class="btn btn-default btn-small">Cancel</a> <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Futhermore there seems to be a problem with the naming of the getter and setter. Mine were like:

```
setBoolean(boolean b){
    this.b = b;
}

isBoolean(){
    return b;
}
```

Spring or thymeleaf (i don't know which component is responsible) seems to need the getter starting with get. After changing this it's working now.

```
setBoolean(boolean b){
    this.b = b;
}

getBoolean(){
    return b;
}
```